# import data from excel to oracle database table

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have excel file which have following column  NAME  RICE   SUGAR   TEA.i want to import all data into my oracle database please see image below.
[image: EXCEL FILE DATA FORMAT]

[image: ORACLE DATABASE TABLE RESULT]

Comment: I think it is more of a `Excel` [question](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/705-excel-convert-table-to-list.html) than `Oracle question`...unless you import the first table 'as is' and then transform it.

Comment: Oracle 10g - are you sure?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is in the range `A2:D5` then you can put the formula below into `E3` and copy it across the range `E3:G5`:

```
="INSERT INTO table_name ( name, item, quantity ) VALUES ( '" & $A3 & "', '" & B$2 & "', " & B3 & ");"
```

Then just copy the generated SQL statements and run them in Oracle.

You could also import the data using SQL Developer and then use a query with `UNPIVOT` to transform columns to rows but for this small a volume of data I would not bother.

Something like:

```
SELECT name, item, quantity
FROM   your_imported_table
UNPIVOT ( quantity FOR item IN ( RICE, TEA, SUGAR ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to import data from excel to Oracle. Create external table using excel and use it. It is best way to use new feature of Oracle. You can join both table for running report or queries. If you change excel (or dump more data in excel sheet) then no need to create again external table because it automatically takes effect.

Comment: Could you, please, post an example which shows how to do that? I'm not sure that *external table* is capable of working with native Excel file (XLS(X)). No problem when saved as a CSV, but XLS? I'd like to see it, if it's not a problem. As of a *new feature*: what is a *new feature*? External tables? If so, well, they were introduced in Oracle 9i in 2003 so - that's not really a *new* feature.

Comment: How can you create external table using excel spreadsheet. You can find out from following link...https://blogs.oracle.com/warehousebuilder/loading-an-excel-spreadsheet-into-an-oracle-table

Comment: Thank you, I read it. It proves you wrong. In order to use **native** Excel files, you need Oracle Warehouse Builder using Heterogeneous Services. In order to use **external tables**, those XLS(X) files have to be saved as a **CSV**.